# Should I use "portion" or "proportion"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage

I have some balls, and some percentage q \in (0, 100%) of them are green (for example, q = 30% or 1/3). Should I say

"A portion q of the balls are green" or

"A proportion q of the balls are green"?

Or any other way I can express it clearly?

Thank you!

Comment: @Jim Thank you for the comment. I am actually considering a mathematical expression, and whether I should say a portion q or proportion q, where q is a percentage. I have modified my question accordingly.

Comment: The word *proportion* could refer to the fraction of the balls that are green, but couldn't refer to the balls themselves. So, you could say *The proportion of balls that are green is 30%.*  Otherwise, as Jim says,use *a portion*, which refers directly to the balls.